# android ListView does not scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem with ListView in my layout which does not scroll. 
I have populated it with custom adapter but after populating it the list view does not scroll and it is locked.
How can I fix it ?
I really appreciate any help.
the xml code for my Listview part is as following:

```
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="4"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

          <ListView
              android:id="@+id/lvDownloads"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Regards

Comment: Try setting the ListView height to `match_parent`, instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: do you have enough items in listView to make it scrollable?

Comment: I changed it to match_parent but its not working again !!

Comment: Yes I have enough items, the remaining items are out of the screen

Comment: Change the Linearlayout height to `match_parent`.